How to configure Python ssl server ciphers to match client's
I'm trying to run this simple socket ssl server in python
import socket, ssl


context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(("", 443))
bindsocket.listen(5)


while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    connstream = context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)
    try:
        data = connstream.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
    finally:
        connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        connstream.close()

but when connecting with client
curl -v https://localhost:443/

I'm getting this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/example/server_ssl.py", line 15, in <module>
    connstream = context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/example/.pyenv/versions/3.11.9/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/example/.pyenv/versions/3.11.9/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1104, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/example/.pyenv/versions/3.11.9/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1382, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:1006)

curl itself shows this error
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* OpenSSL/3.3.1: error:0A000410:SSL routines::ssl/tls alert handshake failure
* closing connection #0
curl: (35) OpenSSL/3.3.1: error:0A000410:SSL routines::ssl/tls alert handshake failure

How to make sure both client/server use same ciphers?
I've tried setting different options for the context, but still getting the same error.
# none of these works
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
context.set_ciphers("ECDHE+AESGCM:ECDHE+CHACHA20:DHE+AESGCM:DHE+CHACHA20")

At this point I don't want to provide any certificates as suggested here, how can I make this code work?

You haven't configured a certificate, so only unauthenticated ciphersuites can be offered and most clients will sensibly refuse to connect. Perhaps there's a way or an option to force the client to accept an "anonymous" ciphersuite

Tried setting context.set_ciphers("aNULL") and doing curl -v -k --ciphers aNULL https://localhost:443/ with the same error even that curl says this cipher is used * Cipher selection: aNULL

Yeah, you probably need to configure the Python SSL server to send those ciphersuites too. I'll see if I can manage to do this later.

After doing a little research, I think the only sensible solution is to use server certificates. TLS 1.3 doesn't even have anonymous ciphersuites, so you'd have to use TLS 1.2 and below. Furthermore, most client software can be configured to basically completely skip verifying/validating the certificate. The resulting connection is essentially similar in security to an anonymous DH ciphersuite. It's not hard to create self-signed certificates in advance or on-the-fly, within python or by using external tools like keytool or openssl.
